# Getting a reversed slice of an array that includes the base element

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, slice

I'm using numpy arrays. I'm trying to calculate an array that contains the products of elements spreading out from some center. My code curently looks like this, where `psi` is a `numpy.array()`:

```
up=psi[position:position+width]
pre_down=psi[position-width+1:position+1]
down=pre_down[::-1]
ac=up*down
```

**Is there a more elegant, pythonic way to make the array "down"?** Something like

```
down=psi[position:position-width:-1]
```

doesn't work when `position-width` is 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you need to slice down to element 0, you can use `None` for the end of the slice.

```
end = position - width - 1 if position > width else None
down = psi[position:end:-1]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `or` keyword to replace the value `0` with `None`, giving you the base element.

```
down=psi[position:position-width or None:-1]
```

Comment: What does `or` do in an index?

Comment: Same thing it does anywhere else. Basically, you're saying you want `position-width` if it's nonzero, or `1` otherwise.

Comment: Ben your answer got flagged for review because there is no explanation. Maybe add a short bit of preface or explanation?

Comment: @Dan `or` was commonly used for ternary expressions in Python back before `if/else` was added for the purpose. In this case I don't think it expresses the intent of the questioner.

Comment: @kindall: I don't want `1` otherwise, I want the base element, so `None` I guess.